# How to keymap the key for moving to end of text file?

Tags: keyboard

How to keymap the key for moving to end of text file?

Hi,

My keyboard is broken so I am remapping the keys with the otherwise interesting KeyMapper app.

However I cannot find the code for moving to the end of a text file. My text files are huge so I want to go directly to the end. Anyone know the keycode for this key? It's not just KEYCODE_MOVE_END, I have tested that and it only takes me to the end of the line, not to the end of the file.

Comment: Try to combine KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT and KEYCODE_MOVE_END

Comment: I think the app does not allow combining.